# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, material-ui, styled-components

I get this issue while using `@mui/material` Autocomplete , It could be because of the `@mui/material` TextField

[image]

```
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
```

```
<Autocomplete
              id="free-solo-demo"
              options={["a", "b", "c"]}
              getOptionLabel={option => (option ? option.name : "")}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="freeSolo"
                  margin="normal"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                />
              )}
            />
```

This is not working and throws the above error

I have try looking into the documentation but i haven't gotten any result from it

Comment: Can you also attach a reproducible [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) link which will help us debug the issue and playaround with the code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/ilyaskarim/iconapp/draft/silly-golick?file=%2Fpages%2F_app.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A7%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A14%2C%22startColumn%22%3A7%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A14%7D%5D

in the codesanbox code the issue is the same

Comment: It isn't opening. Have you published it? To verify, try opening the link in a incognito window.